# GRETA C++ VC11 Undefined Struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am in the process of upgrading a VS2002 C++ Project to VS2013. The Project uses the GRETA regex library. From what I see it is not maintained, and I cannot find an updated version anywhere. I want to change as little of my project as possible, so I would not like to replace GRETA.

restack.h (original)

```
namespace detail
{

// For compile-time assertions that generate
// no run-time overhead.
template< bool f > struct static_assert;
template<>         struct static_assert<true> { static_assert() {} };

// Work-around for a template-template parameter problem on VC7.0
template< typename T > struct type2type { typedef T type; };

template< bool F > struct bool2type { enum { value = F }; };

typedef bool2type<true>  true_t;
typedef bool2type<false> false_t;
```

restack.h (modified)

```
namespace regex
{

    namespace detail
    {

        // For compile-time assertions that generate
        // no run-time overhead.
        template< bool f > struct t_static_assert;
        template<>         struct t_static_assert < true > { t_static_assert() { } };

        // Work-around for a template-template parameter problem on VC7.0
        template< typename T > struct type2type { typedef T type; };

        template< bool F > struct bool2type { enum { value = F }; };

        typedef bool2type<true>  true_t;
        typedef bool2type<false> false_t;
```

I beleive I was having a problem because static_assert is a keyword in VC11 and was not in VC6. So I added the t_ to the front. Now I get this compiler error in regexpr2.h:

```
 error C2079: 'iterator_types_are_not_convertible' uses undefined
 struct 'regex::detail::t_static_assert<false>'
```

regexpr2.h (modified)

```
// If your compile breaks here, it is because CharT* is not
// convertible to type IterT. Check the declaration of your rpattern object.
detail::t_static_assert< detail::is_convertible<CharT*, IterT>::value > const iterator_types_are_not_convertible;
( void ) iterator_types_are_not_convertible;
```

GRETA is avialable here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/bd99f343-4ff4-4041-8293-34c054efe749/default.aspx

How can I go about solving this?

Comment: static_assert is part of C++11 - the purpose of which is to provide compile time asserts

Comment: One of the static asserts is failing -- in particular `detail::is_convertible<CharT*, IterT>`. Without knowing what these types are we can't really say why this test fails.

Comment: I know static_assert is part of C++11, but was it part of VC6? I am thinking it was used in a different context when the library was written.

Comment: I understand a little more now. The code was written before static_assert existed, so it looks like they tried implementing a custom version. I removed all that and switched to the built in. I have found the line of code causing the problem but do not understand what is wrong. This is very old code from Microsoft and probably not worth using anymore.